# Do I need to change JavaScript code to include numeric values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax file uploader plugin ([Max's File Uploader](http://www.phpf1.com/product/file-upload-script.html)) where I copy and pasted the code and made some alterations.

Now below is a jQuery code where it measures if the file is successful, unsuccessful or cancelled:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

  var result = '';
  imagecounter++;

  var replaceForm = function(result) { 
    $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" class="fileImage" type="file"/></label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label><label><input type="button" name="imageClear" class="imageClear" value="Clear File"/></label>');
  } 

  var updateForm = function(result) { 
    $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.display_content_image').html(result);
  } 

  var displayInfo;

  if (success === 1){
    result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span><br/><br/>';      
    $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
    displayInfo = replaceForm;      
  }
  else if (success === 2){
    result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was canceled</span><br/><br/>';
    displayInfo = updateForm;    
  }
  else {
    result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span><br/><br/>';
    displayInfo = updateForm;  
  }
  displayInfo(result); 

)};
```

But I have a JavaScript function where it outputs this below in the PHP script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');
</script>
```

What my question is, though, is that where it says 'true' or 'false' above, should this be 1 : 2 because I am measuring success of the files using numeric values and not string values?

Comment: Looking at the above code, yes it must either be `1` or `2`. However, because you're only using it as a Boolean value, you should refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `true` and `false`  you can use 1 and 2.

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 1 : 2; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```